# how it's possible to show from a post of a custom post type the taxonomy/terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, terms

[RESOLVED]Passing through a taxonomy filter, it gives a postype result of custom post type. I am programming the results as a kind of post grid.

The problem that I am seeing it's that I have no way to get the terms from other taxonomies of the post type that results after filtering.

What I've been trying till now required a post ID, or $taxonomy,... and this depends on the results in the archive-{post-type}.php or taxonomy.php.

Wich kind of function should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

that's the way,
 aha aha,
 and I like it,
 aha aha...

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'oil' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->slug ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
 } } ?>
```